# Anotate a List within a Presentation: As good/ok/bad

Tags: text, symbolism

I want to get away from:

ticks & crosses - crosses give an impression something is wrong;
red/amber/green - red gives the impression something is wrong;
Thumbs Up, down and sideways - its not the colosseum in Rome!

Has anyone come up with a colour scheme? or a set of three characters?

---

Let me take out "bad". 10 items on a list has to be marked as "Very Good", "Good" or "Adequate/not yet developed"

Comment: This is a potentially good question, but as it is I can not understand how is your list. Every item should be qualified as good, ok or bad?

Or just a checked mark.

Comment: Let me take out "bad". Each of the 10 items on the list has to be marked as "Very Good", "Good" or "Adequate/not yet developed"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the presentation is not highly formal, you could go with smileys (but please no emoji). This might sound somewhat childish, but can turn out suprisingly good.

Some examples

Good 
Ok 
Bad

If you like the idea, have a look at the [unicodeblock of smileys](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicodeblock_Smileys).

Answer (score 1):

So, for this "Above Average", "Expected", "Below Average" points.
You don't want to express that some thing is just "wrong" per se, but under the desirable.

Since *Ok* and *Good* are actually *Good* and *Very Good* You can color them as blue/green, Very Good being an upward green triangle. Good being a blue circle or square, seeming stationary and impartially positioned. and for the "Bad" i think a rectangle resembling a minus symbol would be okay since it is neither too harsh as a X mark, nor too disappointing as a downward triangle. As for the colors, something in the range of orangish-yellow would convey the concept of "insufficient" while not giving the idea of "downright bad".

You can even opt out of using colors as well, just symbols, even though this could be a little counter-intuitive for the ones you are presenting to.

Comment: Am trying to say:

Comment: good is better than industry standard; ok is industry standard or "where you should be for the age of your company"; bad is "needs more work to make it effective" or maybe they just haven't focused on that issue yet